# Electron Forge - Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'path'

Tags: windows, electron, packaging, electron-forge

When running `npm run package`, I got the following error:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\Repos\app\out\app-win32-x64'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'D:\\Repos\\app\\out\\app-win32-x64'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

What is causing this error, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I forgot to call `app.quit()` and `[app-name].exe` is still running in the background, kill all instances of `app.exe` and then retry removed the error.

Comment: This fixed my problem. If ``"name": "foo"`` is in `package.json`, it will be `foo.exe`. In cmd, to show whether there is any foo.exe running:  ``tasklist |grep foo.exe``. (Running-away foo.exe can happen after an abnormal termination of foo.exe, for example after an exceptin is thrown.) To kill foo.exe: ``taskkill /f /im foo.exe``.